# Can't remove an unwanted GitHub file

Tags: github

When I try to remove an unwanted GitHub file, the file doesn't disappear.  I am following the instructions at https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/. 
 Is the filename in the format /GitHub/*repositoryname*/?

Comment: What does Dropbox have to deal with GitHub?

Answer (score 1):

Following the instructions in the URL, I CDed to the repository folder.  I typed filename in the following command instead of the full path and it worked:

git filter-branch --force --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filename" --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all